# How to horizontally scroll the ScrollView on the click of the button in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am making an iPhone app which has a scrollview.

I have a button on left and right side of the scrollview. On click of these two buttons the scrollview should scroll in the respective horizontal direction.

What should I do to scroll the scroll view on the click of these buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect  animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 3):

given a scrollview called `scrollView`, call

```
NSInteger page = ..// determine page
CGPoint off = CGPointMake(page*scrollView.frame.size.width,0);
[scrollView setContentOffset:off animated:YES];
```

you could determine the current page by calculating

```
NSInteger page = scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width;
```

Then page `page++;` before setting the new offset.

Answer (score 1):

sample code:

```
float width = scrollView.frame.size.width;
float height = scrollView.frame.size.height;
float newPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.x+width; // or -
// probably check if position is negative
CGRect toVisible = CGRectMake(newPosition, 0, width, height);
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:toVisible animated:YES];
```